# How to make php show the value of a cookie?

Tags: php

So, I was making cookies, and I wanted to take the input from a textbox in a variable, and then, that variable will be the value of a cookie.
When it was set, I wanted it to be shown, but it gave me errors.

```php
$subject = $_POST['mt'];
$content = $_POST['topic'];
$password= $_POST['par'];
$mat = mat;
setrawcookie($mat, $content, time() + (60*60*24*7), "/"); //604800 = 1w
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$mat])) {
            echo "Refresh the page!";
        }
        else {
            header("location:index.html");
        }
```

How can I show it?

Comment: *"... but it gave me errors"* - that's not terribly descriptive, *what* errors did it give you?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable and 
Notice: Undefined index

Comment: Sorry to bother your time, but I found the solution.Had to type $_COOKIE["mat"]; in order to print it. Anyway, thank you very much for responding!

Comment: `$mat = mat` is PHP looking for a defined variable? If this is a string, use quotes.